# Proving following determinant formula

Tags: matrices, determinant

I am facing a problem where I'd appreciate some help:

It is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $R$ be a commutative ring with $a_0,...,a_{n-1} \in R$. Show the following:
$\det(tI_n - A) =t^n - \sum\nolimits_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i t^i$ for $t \in R$ and

$A= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & & & & & a_0 \\
1 & 0 &  & & & a_1\\
 & 1 &  0 & & & a_2 \\
 & &  \ddots & \ddots  & & \vdots\\
 & & & 1 & 0 & a_{n-2}\\
 & & & & 1 & a_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}$

My idea was solving it through induction. The initial step works fine and I planned using the Laplace expansion of the determinant in the induction step to get the matrix to a level where I could apply the induction hypothesis, but it isn't working well. Therefore a hint would be gracious.

Thx in advance!

Comment: FWIW this is a duplicate of [Show the determinant of a matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124709/show-the-determinant-of-a-matrix).

Comment: HInt: Laplace expansion along the last column.  No *real* induction is needed.

Comment: @johny hunter: i wrote an answer to your question in the link suggested by dxiv. Note however that your question is a duplicate of the one dxiv is refering to, so make sure next time you really search this site well on any results which might help you. Kind regards

Comment: I appreciate the advice, I will make sure to do so next time